# Entities with same name, inserting always for the first id

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jpa

I have a `jCombobox` where i load all the Student `entities`.
It is possible to have two students with same `name`, then both are loaded into the `jComboBox`.

The problem is that when i `insert` the data into the `database`, no matter which one of those two students i select in the `jcombobox`, it is inserted always for the first "`id`" (in this case the students with same name are `id` 1, and `id` 6), so it is always inserted for the student with `id` 1..

For sure i'm missing something, can someone help to find what it is?Thanks for now.

I added some codes, see if is better to understand now, thanks.

`Entity` Condutor:

```
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate(value=true)
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Condutor.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Condutor c"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Condutor.findByCondutorId", query = "SELECT c FROM Condutor c WHERE c.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Condutor.findByCondutorNome", query = "SELECT c FROM Condutor c WHERE c.nome = :nome")})
public class Condutor implements EntidadeBase, Serializable {

    @Id

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "idCondutor")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "nomeCondutor")
    private String nome;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "setorCondutor")
    private Setor setor;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "pessoaCondutor")
    private Pessoa pessoa;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "empresaCondutor")
    private Empresa empresa;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "statusCondutor")
    private Status status;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "condutor", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<CondutorInfracao> condInfracoes;

    public Condutor() {
    }

    public Condutor(String nome, Setor setor, Pessoa pessoa, Empresa empresa, Status status) {

        this.nome = nome;
        this.setor = setor;
        this.pessoa = pessoa;
        this.empresa = empresa;
        this.status = status;
    }

    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the nome
     */
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    /**
     * @param nome the nome to set
     */
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    /**
     * @return the setor
     */
    public Setor getSetor() {
        return setor;
    }

    /**
     * @param setor the setor to set
     */
    public void setSetor(Setor setor) {
        this.setor = setor;
    }

    public Pessoa getPessoa() {
        return pessoa;
    }

    public void setPessoa(Pessoa pessoa) {
        this.pessoa = pessoa;
    }

    public Empresa getEmpresa() {
        return empresa;
    }

    public void setEmpresa(Empresa empresa) {
        this.empresa = empresa;
    }

    public Status getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Status status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public List<CondutorInfracao> getCondInfracoes() {
        return condInfracoes;
    }

    public void setCondInfracoes(List<CondutorInfracao> condInfracoes) {
        this.condInfracoes = condInfracoes;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 73 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.id);
        hash = 73 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.nome);
        hash = 73 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.setor);
        hash = 73 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.pessoa);
        hash = 73 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.empresa);
        hash = 73 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.status);
        hash = 73 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.condInfracoes);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Condutor other = (Condutor) obj;
        if (!Objects.equals(this.id, other.id)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.nome, other.nome)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.setor, other.setor)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.pessoa, other.pessoa)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.empresa, other.empresa)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.status, other.status)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.condInfracoes, other.condInfracoes)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.nome;
    }

    @Override
    public Serializable getId() {
        return id;
    }

}
```

`Entity` CondutorInfracao:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "condutorinfracao")
//@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(dynamicUpdate = true)
@DynamicUpdate(value = true)
//@SelectBeforeUpdate(value=true) 
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "CondutorInfracao.findAll", query = "SELECT s FROM CondutorInfracao s"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "CondutorInfracao.findByCondutorInfracaoId", query = "SELECT s FROM CondutorInfracao s WHERE s.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "CondutorInfracao.teste", query = "SELECT s.condutor, ss.id FROM CondutorInfracao s join s.condutor ss"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "CondutorInfracao.testeData", query = "SELECT ss.id, s.condutor,s.dataInfracao,s.linha,s.valor_infracao  FROM CondutorInfracao s join s.condutor ss where s.dataInfracao between :dataInicial and :dataFinal"),})
public class CondutorInfracao implements Serializable, EntidadeBase {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "idCondInf")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "dataInfracaoCondInf")
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dataInfracao;
    @Column(name = "valorCondInf")
    BigDecimal valor_infracao;
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "anexoCondInf")
    private byte[] anexo;
    @Column(name = "anexoExtCondInf")
    private String extensaoArquivo;
    @Column(name = "anexoNomeCondInf")
    private String nomeArquivo;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "condutorCondInf", referencedColumnName = "idCondutor")
    private Condutor condutor;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "linhaCondInf", referencedColumnName = "idLinha")
    private Linha linha;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "infracaoCondInf", referencedColumnName = "idInfracao")
    private Infracao infracao;

    public Date getDataInfracao() {
        return dataInfracao;
    }

    public void setDataInfracao(Date dataInfracao) {
        this.dataInfracao = dataInfracao;
    }

    public Condutor getCondutor() {
        return condutor;
    }

    public Linha getLinha() {
        return linha;
    }

    public void setLinha(Linha linha) {
        this.linha = linha;
    }

    public String getExtensaoArquivo() {
        return extensaoArquivo;
    }

    public void setExtensaoArquivo(String extensaoArquivo) {
        this.extensaoArquivo = extensaoArquivo;
    }

    public String getNomeArquivo() {
        return nomeArquivo;
    }

    public void setNomeArquivo(String nomeArquivo) {
        this.nomeArquivo = nomeArquivo;
    }

    public byte[] getAnexo() {
        return anexo;
    }

    public void setAnexo(byte[] anexo) {
        this.anexo = anexo;
    }

    public void setCondutor(Condutor condutor) {
        this.condutor = condutor;
    }

    public Infracao getInfracao() {
        return infracao;
    }

    public void setInfracao(Infracao infracao) {
        this.infracao = infracao;
    }

    @Override

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

//    public long getCondutor_id() {
//        return condutor_id;
//    }
//
//    public void setCondutor_id(long condutor_id) {
//        this.condutor_id = condutor_id;
//    }
//
//    public long getInfracao_id() {
//        return infracao_id;
//    }
//
//    public void setInfracao_id(long infracao_id) {
//        this.infracao_id = infracao_id;
//    }
    public BigDecimal getValor_infracao() {
        return valor_infracao;
    }

    public void setValor_infracao(BigDecimal valor_infracao) {
        this.valor_infracao = valor_infracao;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 29 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.id);
        hash = 29 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.valor_infracao);
        hash = 29 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.condutor);
        hash = 29 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.infracao);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final CondutorInfracao other = (CondutorInfracao) obj;
        if (!Objects.equals(this.id, other.id)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.valor_infracao, other.valor_infracao)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.condutor, other.condutor)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.infracao, other.infracao)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Code for `saveButtton`:

```
 private void saveButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)    {                                           

CondutorInfracao condutorInfracao = new CondutorInfracao();
condutorInfracao.setCondutor((Condutor) jCCondutor.getSelectedItem());
condutorInfracao.setInfracao((Infracao) jCInfracaoDescr.getSelectedItem());
condutorInfracao.setLinha((Linha) jCLinhaDescr.getSelectedItem());


condutorInfracao.setDataInfracao(dataParaInserir(data));
System.out.println("DATA " +dataParaInserir(data));
Locale brasil = new Locale("pt", "BR");
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(brasil);
String str = valorField.getText();
Number str2 = null;
try {
    str2 = nf.parse(str);
} catch (ParseException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(CondutorInfracaoView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(str2.doubleValue());
BigDecimal ajusted = bd.setScale(nf.getMaximumFractionDigits(), BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
condutorInfracao.setValor_infracao(ajusted);


try {
    CondutorInfracaoDao ci = new CondutorInfracaoDao();
    ci.save(condutorInfracao);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Gravado !");
    modelo.limpaLista();
    preencherTabela();
} catch (Exception erro) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro na Gravação:" + erro);
}
refresh();
clearSelection();
```

}

Method to populate `jComboBox`:

```
  public void loadComboCondutorDescr() {
    AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(this.jCCondutor);
    CondutorDao condutorDao = new CondutorDao();
    List<Condutor> listaCondutores = condutorDao.consultarCondutores();//cria uma lista para receber a lista vindo do dao
    for (Condutor set : listaCondutores) {
        jCCondutor.addItem(set);
    }
}
```

`Class` CondutorDao:

```
public List<Condutor> consultarCondutores() {
EntityManager em = getEm();
List<Condutor> listaCondutores;
try {
    Query q = em.createNamedQuery("Condutor.findAll");
    listaCondutores = q.getResultList();
} catch (Exception e) {
    listaCondutores = new ArrayList<>();

} finally {
    em.close();

}
return listaCondutores;
```

}

Comment: I would guess your Student object needs to implement the `equals(...)` method so that each Student objects with the same name can still be unique.

Comment: So make the row ID the value of the dropdown instead of the name

Comment: @camickr, i added another code part. Is that what you mean?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: I added some more information.

Answer (score 0):

In this case populate the combo box list in to data base.

```
 public void loadComboStudent() {
    AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(this.jCStudent);
    StudentDao studentDao = new StudentDao();
    List<Student> listaStudents = studentDao.consultarStudents();
    for (Student set : listaStudents) {
        jCStudent.addItem(set);
        oc.save(set );
    }
}
```

save this listaStudents  in to database.

Comment: Not sure if it would work, since i just save the `student` after i select one of them from the `jComboBox`, not right after the `JCombobox` is loaded with the `objects`. And a lot of more information about the `student`.

Comment: when you selecting the value than get all the combo box value and save it.

Comment: At this moment you're saying, i just select the `student`, then i set his `phone`, `address` and other things. All those things plus the `student` become the `ocorrencia` . The `listaStudents` is a `return` from a method, not what i want to `insert` into the `database`. hat's why i said wasn't sure if would work, or, i'm not understanding what you said.

Comment: Would it have something to do with [AutoCompleteDecorator](http://javadoc.geotoolkit.org/external/swingx/org/jdesktop/swingx/autocomplete/AutoCompleteDecorator.html)?

Answer (score 0):

After some time looking for the answer, i started to do a step by step test, always i select a `name`in the `jComboBox`, that is listed two times(both have different `Id's`, (just for the make clear)),  when i move the mouse away from the `jComboBox` the selection goes to the one that is listed at the top. That's why it was always doing the `insert`to the same `object`. It doesn't happen with the `names`that are listed just once.