# jComboBox changes selectedItem when selecting repeated itens to the first on list

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

i have a `jComboBox`, it happens that i may have the same value for more than on item. In this case, when selecting one of them, , the selection goes always to the first item on the list. Right after the click.
Have someone experienced that?Have some solution for that, so the selection doesn't change?

When i select:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjlYM.png

Checking again:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1lcQ.png

Answer (score 0):

> it happens that i may have the same value for more than on item.

Then it sounds like you are adding a custom object to the combo box.

If it displays the same value but is a different item, then you need to implement the `equals()` method in your Object so the proper Object can be selected.

If you need more help then post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem because we don't have enough information to keep guessing what you might be doing.

Comment: it is the same codes here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36555069/entities-with-same-name-inserting-always-for-the-first-id , i just made another question because i was thinking it was some problem in my logic, now i guess is more related to the component `jcombobox`

Comment: That is NOT a SSCCE. A SSCCE is simplified code fully contained in a single class that we can copy, compile and test. So you would have a simple Student object (with a couple of parameters). You then create a couple of Students and add then to the combo box. Then you add the combo box to the frame. So the Student class might be 20 lines of code and the code to create the frame another 20 lines of code. Then post the SSCCE and we can maybe help. All the other stuff in that posting is unrelated to the question.

Answer (score 0):

A JComboBox always tries to synchronize what is selected in the lists with what is shown in the display field. To do that, it searches the list sequentially for a match of the editor field. So it will always find the first one if there are identical items in the list. Thus you can't just use String objects if there is a possibility for identical Strings in the list. You need to do what @camickr said and use a custom object that has some way to distinguish between two objects whose toString() method returns the same thing (assuming you use the default model and editor).